# Alpha-numeric regex from a ruby on rails 3 app not working in my ruby on rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my model:

```
class Garment
    include ActiveAttr::Model
    #include ActiveModel::Validations
    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    attribute :title

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    alpha_numeric_regix = /\A[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\z/


    validates :title,       :presence      => true,
                            :length        => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 30 },
                            :format        => {
                                                 :with => alpha_numeric_regix,
                                                 :message => "must contain letters, dashes and underscores only"
                                               }
```

How ever my actual form keeps telling me the validation has failed when I use purely letters and spaces e.g. VA Yellow Top

Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/ynd3DOWCxe

What could the problem be. In rubular using two letter "VA" fails validation as well.

What could be going on?

Comment: You missed the quantifier: http://rubular.com/r/8i5rKNJVv5. Also, space is not in the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\A[a-zA-Z0-9-_]\z/` + `when I use purely letters and spaces` - there is no space in your regex, should be

```
`/\A[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\ ]+\z/`
```